# How to write a cursor inside a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables in my database

**Coupon Table**

- id (int)
- Name (nvarchar(max))
- NoofUses (int)

**CouponUse Table**

- id(int)
- Couponid(int)
- CreateDate(datetime)

Whenever a user clicks on a coupon an entry goes into the `CouponUse` table containing that Coupon's id

Now there is a column in the `coupon` table called `NoofUses`. I want to write a cursor inside a stored procedure which loops over `couponuse` table and sees how many rows are there for one coupon and fill that number in `NoofUses` field in coupon.

I have this query

```
  select COUNT(*) as totalcount , Name as name from Coupon as coupon 
  join CouponUse as couponuse on coupon.id = couponuse.couponid
  group by couponuse.couponid , coupon.Name
```

which gives me the coupon name and its count from `couponuse`

But I don't know how to implement that in a stored procedure using a cursor  ?

Anything you ask about question will be appreciated , Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's wrong with just simply using a single, simple `UPDATE` statement??

```
UPDATE dbo.Coupon
SET NoofUses = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.CouponUse WHERE Couponid = dbo.Coupon.ID)
```

That's all that's needed ! No messy and complicated cursor, no looping, no RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing ..... just a nice, simple, clean set-based SQL statement.

Comment: Great @marc_s , i wish one day i will be a expert in sql like you ... Hats off to you and this is not first time you solved my many problem , Thanks again

Comment: @Smartboy: <hehe> thanks! That's mostly a matter of time&experience - once you're grey & old as I am, you'll be just as wise :-)

Comment: anyway give me any best suggestion you think for learning sql . i mean how can i learn sql to fight with that kind of conditions ,

Answer (score 16):

Try the following snippet. You can call the the below stored procedure from your application, so that `NoOfUses` in the coupon table will be updated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateCouponCount]
AS

Declare     @couponCount int,
            @CouponName nvarchar(50),
            @couponIdFromQuery int


Declare curP cursor For

  select COUNT(*) as totalcount , Name as name,couponuse.couponid  as couponid from Coupon as coupon 
  join CouponUse as couponuse on coupon.id = couponuse.couponid
  where couponuse.id=@cuponId
  group by couponuse.couponid , coupon.Name

OPEN curP 
Fetch Next From curP Into @couponCount, @CouponName,@couponIdFromQuery

While @@Fetch_Status = 0 Begin

    print @couponCount
    print @CouponName

    update Coupon SET NoofUses=@couponCount
    where couponuse.id=@couponIdFromQuery


Fetch Next From curP Into @couponCount, @CouponName,@couponIdFromQuery

End -- End of Fetch

Close curP
Deallocate curP
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: there is a problem @Gowdhaman that this will update only one coupon at a time , i want that when i execute store procedure it update all coupons not a single

Comment: I have edited the query now. Removed the CouponId from the parameter. Added the couponId into the cursor's select query [since it is already] available in your group by statement. Used that Id into the Update statement. This may help you.

Comment: now i am facing this error `Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.
`

Comment: i think we didnot set @couponIdFromQuery anywhere in query

Comment: @Smartboy, I had missed the cuponIdFromQuery in Fetch Next Statement. I have edited the code again.I saw that your issue resolved without using Cursor from marc_s. Good to know that. I thought you really need of the cursor.

Comment: Can anyone tell me me how to retrieve the records in java using Resultset() method?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger which updates `NoofUses` column in `Coupon` table whenever
`couponid` is used in `CouponUse` table

query :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[couponcount] ON [dbo].[couponuse]
FOR INSERT
AS
if EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Inserted)
  BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.Coupon
SET NoofUses = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.CouponUse WHERE Couponid = dbo.Coupon.ID)
end
```