# Loop for each row

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, foreach

I have two tables with `FOREIGN KEY([Table_ID])`

```
Columns

ID       Table_ID       ActiveFlag
1        1              0
2        2              1
3        1              1
4        3              0

Sys_Tables

Table_ID       Name
1              Request
2              Plan
3              Contecst
```

I'm writing a stored procedure that returns any column for each table.

Example Output for values ​​above

```
--first output table
ID       Table_ID       ActiveFlag
1        1              0
3        1              1
--second output table
ID       Table_ID       ActiveFlag
2        2              1
--third output table
ID       Table_ID       ActiveFlag
4        3              0
```

My idea is this

```
Select c.*             
from Ccolumns c
     inner join Sys_tables t
    on t.Table_ID = c.Table_ID and t.Table_ID = @Parameter
```

My problem, i do't know how to make a loop for each row. I need the best way. Example i can use following loop:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @count int;
select @count = count(t.Table_ID)
from Sys_tables t
     WHILE @i < @count BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
--DO ABOVE SELECT   
END
```

But this is not entirely correct. Example my Sys_tables such data may be

```
Table_ID       Name
1              Request
102            Plan
1001           Contecst
```

Do You have any idea?

Comment: The question would be, do you realy need to have seperate result sets for each entry?

Comment: yes, I need! return value contain several tables, count of tables, and something also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways you can achieve that: loops and cursors, but first of all you need to know that it's a bad idea: either are very slow, anyway, here's some kind of loop sample:

```
declare @row_ids table (
    id INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
    rid INT
); 
insert into @row_ids (rid) select someIdField from SomeTable

declare @cnt INT = @@ROWCOUNT
declare @currentRow INT = 1

WHILE (@currentRow <= @cnt)
BEGIN
    SELECT rid FROM @row_ids WHERE id = @currentRow
    SET @currentRow = @currentRow + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using SQL Server, right?

Then, you can use a `CURSOR` as here: [How to write a cursor inside a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507317/how-to-write-a-cursor-inside-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)