# Sql Server - Cursor not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm using AdventureWorks ( Sql server 2005 express) and want to find out if which gender has highes leave hours with the following SP.
The SP compiles well but is not showing any result on execution

here is the sp

```
create proc GenderLeaveCount
as
begin
declare @gender nchar(1)
declare @leaveHours smallint

declare @totalHoursMale int
declare @totalHoursFemale int

declare genderLeave Cursor
for select Gender , SickLeaveHours
from HumanResources.Employee
where SickLeaveHours is not null and Gender is not null


open genderLeave

fetch next from genderLeave 
into @gender,@leaveHours

while @@fetch_status=0
Begin
    IF @gender = N'M'
        Set @totalHoursMale = @totalHoursMale + @leaveHours
    ELSE
        Set @totalHoursFemale = @totalHoursFemale + @leaveHours

    fetch next from genderLeave 
    into @gender,@leaveHours

End

close genderLeave
deallocate genderLeave

IF @totalHoursMale > @totalHoursFemale
    Select 'Male leave hours are higher:' + cast(@totalHoursMale as varchar(20))as result
IF @totalHoursMale < @totalHoursFemale
    Select 'Male leave hours are higher:' + cast(@totalHoursMale as varchar(20))as result
IF @totalHoursMale = @totalHoursFemale
    Select 'Male leave hours are higher:' + cast(@totalHoursMale as varchar(20)) as result

end
go
exec GenderLeaveCount
```

---

Can anyone please let me know what the issue is and how to fix it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a cursor inside a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507317/how-to-write-a-cursor-inside-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: You need to make `@totalHoursMale` and `@totalHoursFemale` equal to 0. This is not VBScript where uninitialized variables get set to 0 through magic when they are referenced later. Right now you are adding `NULL + @leaveHours` which equals `NULL`, so there is nothing to print because when you concatenate `NULL` to your string this also yields `NULL`. Anyway, isn't it much, much, much, much, much more efficient to just `SELECT Gender, SUM(LeaveHours) ... GROUP BY Gender;` and then print the conditional message on the client?

Comment: @AsheshKumar I really don't see how that is a duplicate.

Comment: (Oh, and debugging 101, `SELECT` your variables inside the loop...)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Aaron Bertrand..

:)

.net has 0 as default for all variables...i wonder why MS didn't give default to sql server variables..

I initialized and it now works..sometimes i get too lost in the fetch and other syntaxes and fail to notice such minute slips of code.  I'm using this sp to demonstrate how to use cursors with a while statement to my students, i know its not the best example, I could have used a TVF too.
Here is the soultion after incorporating the changes.

```
create proc GenderLeaveCount
as
begin
declare @gender nchar(1)
declare @leaveHours smallint

declare @totalHoursMale int
declare @totalHoursFemale int

set @totalHoursMale = 0
set @totalHoursFemale = 0

declare genderLeave Cursor
for select Gender , SickLeaveHours
from HumanResources.Employee
where SickLeaveHours is not null and Gender is not null


open genderLeave

fetch next from genderLeave 
into @gender,@leaveHours

while @@fetch_status=0
Begin
    IF @gender = N'M'
        Set @totalHoursMale = @totalHoursMale + @leaveHours
    ELSE
        Set @totalHoursFemale = @totalHoursFemale + @leaveHours

    fetch next from genderLeave 
    into @gender,@leaveHours

End

close genderLeave
deallocate genderLeave

IF @totalHoursMale > @totalHoursFemale
    Select 'Male leave hours are higher:' + cast(@totalHoursMale as varchar(20))as result
IF @totalHoursMale < @totalHoursFemale
    Select 'Female leave hours are higher:' + cast(@totalHoursMale as varchar(20))as result
IF @totalHoursMale = @totalHoursFemale
    Select 'Male and Female Leave hours are equal:' + cast(@totalHoursMale as varchar(20)) as result
end
```

---

Comment: Because SQL Server existed years before .NET was even dreamed up? Also, are you talking about classic VB? I'm pretty sure .net has nullable variables where everything uninstantiated doesn't magically become 0. *shrug* SQL Server is doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query instead of cursor in your query:
Cursor have low performance than following query:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN [M]>[F] THEN 'Male leave hours are higher:' + cast(@M as varchar(20))
        WHEN [M]<[F] THEN 'Male leave hours are higher:' + cast(@M as varchar(20))
        WHEN [M]=[F] THEN 'Male leave hours are higher:' + cast(@M as varchar(20))
    END as result
FROM (SELECT Gender, SUM(SickLeaveHours) AS TotalHours
    FROM HumanResources.Employee
    WHERE SickLeaveHours is not null and Gender is not null
    GROUP BY Gender
    )p
PIVOT ( SUM(TotalHours) FOR Gender IN ([M],[F]))pvt
```